# how to update repositories in Alpine

Tags: package-management, repository, alpine-linux, apk-tools

I am trying to get the latest version of the "consul" package.

the current available and installed package is version `1.10.6` but the latest is [`1.11.1`](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/community/armhf/consul)

```
sudo apk list | grep consul
consul-template-openrc-0.27.2-r0 aarch64 {consul-template} (MPL-2.0)
consul-openrc-1.10.6-r0 aarch64 {consul} (MPL-2.0) [installed]
consul-template-0.27.2-r0 aarch64 {consul-template} (MPL-2.0)
consul-1.10.6-r0 aarch64 {consul} (MPL-2.0) [installed]
```

I've tried to update and add the repository but it states that there is conflict between the two versions

```
sudo apk upgrade
ul=1.11.1-r0OK: 1516 MiB in 190 packages

sudo apk update
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.15/main/aarch64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.15/community/aarch64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.15/main/aarch64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
v3.15.0-145-g123e3b9a98 [https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.15/main]
v3.15.0-152-gfc0468af85 [https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.15/community]
v3.15.0-145-g123e3b9a98 [http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.15/main]
OK: 15705 distinct packages available

sudo apk add consul=1.11.1-r0
ERROR: unable to select packages:
  consul-1.10.6-r0:
    breaks: world[consul=1.11.1-r0]
```

what is the best way to solve this kind of issues in Alpine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According with the screenshot you have pasted, you have not added the edge repository, rather you are stick to v3.15.

`consul-1.11.1-r0` is available only in edge repository.

You can verify this by comparing the output of:

https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=consul&branch=v3.15

with :

https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=consul&branch=edge

That mean that apk is behaving correctly.

If you want to add consul from edge repository, you can use the pinning[1] feature of apk, in this way:

```
# echo "@edge http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories
```

Now, you can add a specific package within community repository in this way:

```
# apk add consul@edge
```

Hope it helps.

.: Francesco

[1] https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Package_management#Repository_pinning